# ASP.NET Core - The instance of entity type cannot be tracked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've encountered an issue when trying to update my context in my Edit action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(Model.LeaveApplication leaveApplication) {

ViewBag.Title = "Edit Leave Application";
ViewBag.leavePeriodList = context.LeavePeriod.ToList();
ViewBag.LeaveTypeList = context.LeaveType.ToList();

try {    
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {    
        if (!validateDateRanges(leaveApplication, "edit")) {    
            return View(leaveApplication);
        }

        leaveApplication.NumDays = (float)CalculateNoOfDays(leaveApplication);
        context.LeaveApplication.Update(leaveApplication);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }    
}
catch (DbUpdateException) {    
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to edit leave application. " +
    "Please try again, and if the problem persists, " +
    "please see your system administrator.");
}              
    return View(leaveApplication);
}
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is to check if there is more than 1 records in order to validate date ranges. If there is only 1 record, I will then skip the validation and proceed to update the context. However, I get an error saying:

> The instance of entity type 'LeaveApplication' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked.

What is causing this problem?

Here is my constructor code:

```
public class LeaveApplicationController : Controller {

    LeaveDBContext context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;

    public LeaveApplicationController(LeaveDBContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager) {

        this.context = context;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other DbContext instance than *the context* ? It happened to me when I try to reach the same entity object by two context instances. If this is the problem, you should either use single context or untrack after reaching it with other context

Comment: No, I don't think I have any other DbContext instance, but I do have a UserDbContext. In my constructor I have included the parameters `LeaveDbContext`, `UserManager<ApplicationUser` and `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>`.

Comment: Can you post your constructor code?

Comment: @PavelLevchuk Okay, I've updated my question to include the constructor code

Comment: @iamhx, you probably access same entity with UserDbContext. You can untrack the entity by detaching it; context.Entry(leaveApplication).State = EntityState.Detached;

Comment: @iamhx What happens in `CalculateNoOfDays` method?

Comment: @PavelLevchuk just a bunch of `switch` statements to calculate and return a value to `leaveApplication.NumDays`

Comment: @Progressive I tried putting your code just before `context.LeaveApplication.Update(leaveApplication)`. Still doesn't work...

Comment: @iamhx What if you remove `context.LeaveApplication.Update(leaveApplication);` and just leave `SaveChanges`?

Comment: @PavelLevchuk the record doesn't get updated; stays the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* attempt to save an object created via a post. There's a number of security reasons why this is the case, but you've also stumbled onto a practical one based on the way EF works.

It's hard to tell exactly without more of your codebase, but at some point this particular `LeaveApplication` instance is loaded into your context, which then begins tracking it. When you attempt to save a *different* `LeaveApplication` instance (i.e. the one that was posted), EF cannot because it's not tracking *that* instance, but rather the one that was loaded earlier.

What you should do instead is post to a view model class. Then, pull the `LeaveApplication` instance you want to edit directly from your context, and map over the data from your view model onto it. Finally, save that instance. Then, you will no longer have any issues, *and* you get the side benefits of preventing over-post hacks and other post-data tampering. Also, your `LeaveApplication` id should be part of the URL. *Never* trust a posted id. Period. Since an id in the URL uniquely identifies the resource, you can easily implement object-level permissions based on that.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very informative. I will go ahead and change it into a view model now and let you know if it works!

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I will definitely take note of this in the future.